# File separator character in Java on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: java, windows-7, java-7

Please refer to simple constant declarations below:

```
String FILE_Separator = new String (new char[] {File.separatorChar});

String OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME = "OUTPUT";   

String PREFIX_PATH = "."+FILE_Separator+"bin"+FILE_Separator;   

String OFFER_LETTER_DIR_PATH = PREFIX_PATH + OFFER_LETTER_FOLDER_NAME + FILE_Separator ;
```

Now the last line prints - `.binOUTPUT` on Windows 7 - 64 bit. However the result is fine on Windows 7 32 - bits. **I am using JDK 7.** Is this a known issue. What's the fix?

Comment: Well this wasn't a problem, as the output String was printed after i18n which was omitting the File separators.

Answer (score 1):

Use `File.separator` which is standard for all `OS`.

```
String FILE_Separator = File.separator;
```

Answer (score 1):

On my computer (Win 7 64 - bit) `OFFER_LETTER_DIR_PATH` is  `.\bin\OUTPUT\`

This is my java version

```
java version "1.7.0_02"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
```

Nevertheless you don't need to create the `FILE_Separator` string just use `File.separator`.